# ImportError after successful installation with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-module, python-packaging

I have created a skeleton package [here](https://github.com/n8ta/mofdb-client), and I cannot seem to build and then test my own project.

src/main.py contains a single function and tests/unit.py tries to import and test that one function with `from mofdb.main import add_one`

```
├── LICENSE
├── dist
│   ├── mofdb-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── mofdb-0.0.3.tar.gz
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── main.py
│   └── mofdb.egg-info
│       ├── PKG-INFO
│       ├── SOURCES.txt
│       ├── dependency_links.txt
│       └── top_level.txt
└── tests
    └── unit.py
```

Here's my attempt to run the tests:

```sh
python3 -m build
python3 -m pip install dist/mofdb-0.0.3.tar.gz
> Successfully installed mofdb-0.0.3

python3 tests.unit.py

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/Users/n8ta/Desktop/mofdb-client/tests/unit.py", line 2, in <module>
>    from mofdb.main import add_one
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mofdb'

python3 -m pip freeze
> matplotlib==3.3.3
> mofdb @ file:///Users/n8ta/Desktop/mofdb-client/dist/mofdb-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
> monty==2021.12.1
> ...
```

You can see from pip freeze that my module exists. But cannot be found for some reason.

And here's my setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = mofdb
version = 0.0.3
author = Nathaniel Tracy-Amoroso
author_email = omitted
description = Simple client for fetching data from mofdb
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/n8ta/mofdb-client
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since I specified the package_dir as `src` that becomes the root and any folders under that are modules. I mistakenly assumed that module name was the package name and that files under `src` would be modules.

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   ├── mofdb <--- THIS DIR IS THE MODULE NAME
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   ├── mofdb.egg-info
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   └── test <-- This would also be an available module
│       └── run.py
```